# jqgrid restorerow not working with paging

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, pagination

There is a jqgrid with 10 records in it. Each record has a button that makes the current row editable. after the edit button is pressed, we populate the old edit field with a save and cancel edit button. After a save/cancel, the edit button is restored. This all works fine until you try and edit a record, then change attempt to change the page to the next 10 records.

```
        var btnSave = "<input style='height:22px;' type='button' value='Save' onclick=\"$('#list').jqGrid('saveRow', '" + rowId + "', null,  '<%= Url.Action("GridSave","Translation")%>', null, aftersavefunc);\" />";
        var btnCancel = "<input style='height:22px;' type='button' value='Cancel' onclick=\"$('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow', '" + rowId + "', aftercancelfunc);\" />";
        $("#list").jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, { act: btnSave + btnCancel });
```

After you hit the edit button, if you try and change the page, a confirmation dialog is presented, warning you that you may be losing changes.

This is within the paging code:

```
onPaging: function (pgButton) {
                    // pgButton: first, last, prev, next, records (# of records ddl), user (user types in new page num)

                    // if in edit mode:
                    var nextPg = $("#list").getGridParam("page");
                    var nextRecords = $("#list").getGridParam("rowNum");


                    if(inEditMode) {
                        var result = confirm("You might be abandoning unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to perform this action?");
                        if (!result) {
                           $("#list").setGridParam({ page: currPg, rowNum: currRecords }); //Workaround - jqGrid still increments the page num even when we return stop so we have to reset it (and track the current page num)
                           return 'stop';
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#list").jqGrid('showCol', ["act"]);
                             }
                    }

                },
```

If you cancel the dialog, you stay on the current page.

The issue we're seeing is if you edit a record, try and change the page, cancel the changing of the page, and try and cancel the editing of the record, the restoreRow never makes the records fields uneditable again. It also changes the save/cancel buttons back to edit.

Whats odd is that saving after doing the same steps works fine. Its just the restoring of the page that is the issue.